# SNI Error Apache2 Logs

Tags: php, apache, ssl, apache2, sni

today I am looking at the logs I found this anomaly in apache2.

```
[ssl:error] [pid 29646] AH02032: Hostname page_not_found provided via SNI and hostname www.site.ltd provided via HTTP are different
```

Since I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject, I read around some guidance but I did not understand a lot about how to fix it ...
In my configuration I have one virtualhost which is the default. Any other file on apache or php are default

I read the problem occurs when you have many virtual hosts with different certificates on a single place, but this is not my case ...

How can i fix the problem? Below can you find the configuration!

PHP 5.6.17-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

/etc/host is default file

default-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.ltd
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
        ServerName www.site.ltd
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/site.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site.key

        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate_site_ca.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be due to a dodgy request from a client (likely a bot) rather than something wrong with your config: https://serverfault.com/questions/561945/conflict-between-sni-and-http-provided-domains

I presume you don't get it for every request? If so check the request around that time and then just ignore it (or block that IP if you really want).